# LINQ statement issue for dynamic view component menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have three level (Category- Subcategory - Nestedcategory) dropdown navigation menu on my website for which data must come dynamically from database. My main problem in generation of InvokeAsync() method to make it work. I can write two levels which work fine as I checked, but confused in defining Nestedcategories - need to get it from subcategories which derived from categories.
Here is my Controller

```
  public class MenuViewComponent: ViewComponent
{
    private readonly SamirDbContext _samirDbContext;

    public MenuViewComponent(SamirDbContext samirDbContext)
    {
        _samirDbContext = samirDbContext;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var menu = await _samirDbContext.Categories.Include(x => x.Subcategories).ThenInclude(y => y.NestedCategories).
                                                  Select(x => new MenusModel()
                                                  {
                                                      Category = x,
                                                      Id = x.Id,
                                                      Subcategories = x.Subcategories,
                                                      **NestedCategories = ...**
                                                  }).ToListAsync();
         
            return View(menu);
                                                                                   
    }
}
```

Here are models:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Subcategories = new HashSet<Subcategory>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
}

public class Subcategory
{
    public Subcategory()
    {
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
        NestedCategories = new HashSet<NestedCategory>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<NestedCategory> NestedCategories { get; set; }
}

public class NestedCategory
{
    public NestedCategory()
    {
        Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
        
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }
    public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Menu ViewModel

```
 public class MenusModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    public Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<NestedCategory> NestedCategories { get; set; }
    public NestedCategory NestedCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Please, help in completion InvokeAsyinc() method in order to get work for 3 level menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectMany() method, change the linq like below:

```
var menu = await _samirDbContext.Categories
    .Select(x => new MenusModel()
    {
        Category = x,
        Id = x.Id,
        Subcategories = x.Subcategories,
        NestedCategories = x.Subcategories.SelectMany(s => s.NestedCategories).ToList()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your models for `Category`, `Subcategory`, and `NestedCategory`, I'm asking myself why you actually could need to have a separate output property (`**NestedCategories = ...**`) in your final `Select` statement.

Let's think this way if the `NestedCategory` is defined inside the `Subcategory` collection, then every `Subcategory` element should have its own list of `NestedCategory`-ies, which will be available when you will check some `Subcategory` from the dropdown.

So, my advice here is to leave the result as follows:

```cs
var menu = await _samirDbContext.Categories
    .Include(x => x.Subcategories)
    .ThenInclude(y => y.NestedCategories)
    .Select(x => new MenusModel()
    {
        Category = x,
        Id = x.Id,
        Subcategories = x.Subcategories
            .Select(sb => new SubcategoryDTO
            {
                sb.Id,
                sb.Name,
                ...
                NestedCategories = sb.NestedCategories
                    .Select(nst => new NestedCategoriesDTO 
                    {
                         nst.Id,
                         nst.Name,
                         ...
                    })
            }), 
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Then you can use the above model in your UI.
Hope this will help ))